# Rodar icon "Arrow" com JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pode parecer simples essa pergunta, mas não consigo encontrar uma resposta de qualidade. Tenho um ícone de seta e quando clicar nela, quero que ela rode 180 graus. O código que comecei a usar foi esse:

```js
$('.arrow').click(function() {
      $('.rodar').toggleClass('rodado');
  });
```

```css
.rodado{
     transform:rotate(180deg);
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons dots green arrow rodar">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
<br>
<i class="material-icons dots green arrow rodar">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
```

Mas como podem ver no exemplo, se clico em uma, as duas rodam. O `this` não funciona. Tem como fazer isso de alguma forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note que nessa linha você está aplicando o efeito em todos os elementos que possuem a classe `rodar`:

```
$('.rodar').toggleClass('rodado');
```

Para pegar apenas o elemento que foi clicado, use o `$(this).`

```js
$('.arrow').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('rodado');
  });
```

```css
.rodado{
     transform:rotate(180deg);
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons dots green arrow rodar">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
<br>
<i class="material-icons dots green arrow rodar">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Estranho é que tentei usar o this, mas não funcionou... deve ter sido algum problema de cache, agora funcionou direitinho, obrigado!

Comment: Ou você usou `this` ao invés de transformá-lo em um objeto jquery, assim `$(this)`

Comment: Você foi mais rápido. hahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio sua resposta também ficou bem elaborada. +1

Answer (score 3):

O método [`jQuery.toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) pertence apenas à biblioteca jQuery, o método [`Element.classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) seria o equivalente JS nativo.

Então, ou você converte o `this` para um objeto jQuery usando o código:

```
$(this).toggleClass("rodado");
```

Ou você usa o elemento nativo usando:

```
this.classList.toggle("rodado");
```

Apenas verifique a [compatibilidade com os navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).

```js
$('.arrow').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rodado');
    // ou
    // this.classList.toggle('rodado')
});
```

```css
.rodado{
     transform:rotate(180deg);
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons dots green arrow rodar">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
<br>
<i class="material-icons dots green arrow rodar">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
```